# Understanding how a template function (with source in .h) relates to its compiled .lib

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Suppose I want to send a C++ class (without source) to my friend Bob.  I would send him a compiled .lib and the given MyClass.h:

```cpp
class MyClass {
  public:
    /// Public template function for safety of size, implementation in .h
    template <class T>
    static int SendData(const T& data) {
        return SendDataUnsafe(&data, sizeof(T));
    };

  private:
    /// Private function with risky size, code implementation in .cpp and compiled in .lib
    static int SendDataUnsafe(PCVOID data, size_t data_size);
};
```

I understand that the source code of `SendDataUnsafe` in MyClass.cpp was compiled and partially linked into a MyClass64.lib (example).  Since it is private, the Bob's compiler won't let him call `SendDataUnsafe` directly (unresolved external).  So Bob must use the templated `SendData` instead.  But I have some questions:

1. Is there anything compiled about the `SendData` template into the .lib, since the implementation is entirely in the .h?
2. Could Bob change the source code of `SendData` (in the .h) and replace `sizeof(T)` by something else to gain indirect access to `SendDataUnsafe`?

**EDIT:** If Bob removes the `private:` statement and tries to call `SendDataUnsafe`, he gets an ERROR (which seems in contradiction to comments received so far):

```
ERROR, LNK2019, unresolved external symbol "public: static int MyClass::SendDataUnsafe(void const *,unsigned __int64)" (...) referenced in function main
```

Comment: `(unresolved external)` No. Static members have external linkage, whether private or not. Otherwise the instantiations of the public function would not be able to call it. What would happen, instead, would not be a linker error, but rather a compiler one (which Bob could work around fairly easily in a number of ways).

Comment: If you want to make it harder for people to know stuff you don't want them to know or harder to do stuff you don't want them to do, take a look at the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: Now suppose I want Bob to use ```SendDataUnsafe```, but I lost the .cpp file, could I simply tell him to remove the ```private:``` statement in the .h?

Answer (score 1):

Bob can absolutely call your private function. private is a compile-time compiler enforced restriction. I'm guessing if Bob were to remove the `private:` line from your header, his code would link fine. **(now tested)**

1. No, the compiler can't generate any meaningful code for SendData.
2. SendDataUnsafe is very visible in your .lib. You can't hide it in any meaningful way.

https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling
Seems to support the conclusion that the mangled name does not include any mention of a private member.

Bob can also add a new function to your .h file and call the private member however he likes.

Comment: That does not seem true. See my Edit.

Comment: @BinaryMonkey I did the same test successfully on g++.